# How to toggle Scroll Lock in Excel 2010 without a Scroll Lock key in the keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010, scroll-lock

I have a notebook with no Scroll Lock key (or any shortcut using the 'Fn' key).

Somehow Excel 2010 got the Scroll Lock on. I see it left down in the status bar and now I can't navigate through cells using the arrow keys, which is pretty annoying. It wasn't turned on some hours ago, so I think I must have hit some Scroll Lock toggle shortcut in Excel 2010 by mistake.

Anyone knows what hot to turn off Scroll Lock in Excel (shortcut or menu option)?

Comment: I also triggered a scroll look somehow.  I was pressing the tab key a bunch or something, was hoping there was an actual shortcut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010se-excel/how-to-disable-scrolllock-in-excel-windows/1c8d8554-b919-4870-9a08-d3e69bb532d1?msgId=c1262b74-1d04-41b6-aeae-51218f3263f9) which refers to the Excel help file:

> "If your keyboard does not have a Scroll Lock key, on your computer,
>   got to Start, All Programs, Accessories, Ease of Access, and then
>   click On-Screen Keyboard. When the on-screen keyboard appears on your
>   screen, click the slk button."

There is a picture of this process at the link.

Comment: Ugh.  So nobody knows how this got toggled on?  I get that it can be fixed with the OSK, but somehow it keeps turning on, I would imagine that repeating that action would disable it.

Comment: You can also invoke the On-Screen Keyboard by typing `osk` into the (Win)+(R) (i.e., "Run") dialog box, or a Command Prompt.

Answer (score 18):

It's 'Fn' + 'S', accidentally pressed instead of 'Ctrl' + 'S', which is the toggle shortcut on my Dell - and most Dells, in general.

Also, 'Fn' + 'C' works for HP Elitebook laptops.
Try if it works for you.

Comment: It doesn't work for the person who originally asked the question because they explicitly say that there's no shortcut using the FN key. But your answer will still be useful to other people so that's fine.

Comment: Worked on my Dell too. Note: there's no indication at all on the key itself that this one is the scroll-lock key.

Comment: 'Fn' + 's' on my Dell invokes my screenshot program! (I have Gadwin Pro installed, so it may not be a native thing)

Comment: 'Shift' + 'Fn' + 's' on Dell Latitude

Comment: Confirmed on Lenovo. Fn+C worked

Answer (score 4):

On an HP Probook 440, <kbd>function</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> locks and unlocks ScrLk.

Comment: Same for  HP EliteBook 840 G3

Answer (score 2):

Scroll Lock option for the Lenovo L 440 Thinkpad can be enabled by using <kbd>Fn+K</kbd> to toggle.

Virtual Keypad option as suggested above OSK also works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel >> Mouse >> Wheel, and click option button: "Use Microsoft Office 97 Scrolling Emulation Only". This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It took a lot of time to find solution for this.

Press below combination to switch off/disable Scroll Lock:

```
Fn + F3
```

Press again to on/enable Scroll Lock.

Comment: This works on my Dell Latitude! Thanks! I used the On-Screen Keyboard to disable it but knew for sure I enabled it by pressing some combined keys.

Answer (score 1):

It is <kbd>Fn+Pause/Break</kbd> on Asus Zenbook (sort of undocumented feature: it is not written on the button).

Comment: but not on linux

Comment: @BerryTsakala I think it must be easier on linux.

Comment: it's voodoo either way. if you know the magical mystery spell book, LMK

Comment: @BerryTsakala yes, voodoo in fact :) I don't have a linux laptop right now, but when I did remapping in general was pretty simple. I don't remember the details, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Lenovo ThinkPad user, use Fn + C to toggle Scroll lock. Otherwise you can always use on screen keyboard ! I used to solve this by using On-Screen Keyboard !

Comment: This also works on HP EliteBooks (and apparently HP Probook 440 as mentioned in another answer).  This comment is here to note this for future users.  I am not sure who downvoted this as this had not been suggested prior to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech K360 wireless keyboard (and possibly others) use <kbd>FN+PgDn</kbd> for scroll lock.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> works on a variety of Dell Studios (including my XPS).

Found [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/no-scroll-lock-key-in-my-dell-studio-17/td-p/4611290)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the On-Screen Keyboard is the easiest way to toggle scroll lock.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> calls and dismisses it.

Answer (score -2):

Fn + K worked for me on my Lenovo L440. I assume this is the shortcut for the Scroll Lock option.

Comment: This duplicates the earlier answer from Kiran. Please read the existing answers (particularly for older questions) before answering.

Answer (score -3):

i got it corrected with OSK but yes it did happen again, that's when i realized HOW it got ON in first place.

Yes i saw qts was posted 3 years ago but a solution is never late right?

It gets ON by pressing FN, CTRL (RHS, besides arrow keys which also works as right click key) and 'S' together. In excel on trying to get 'paste special' i was pressing all these 3 together. What you really need to do is press FN and CTRL (rhs) and then S for 'paste special'.

To undo scroll lock just press FN, (RHS) CTRL and S all together. :) hope it helped.

Comment: What is OSK and what is qts?

Comment: @suspectus OSK = On-Screen Keyboard. I think qts is a typo for qst=question. jabeen, please don't use textspeak and abbreviations: it really doesn't take long to type the word "question".

Comment: I don't see why this answer should be down voted.  Despite the textspeak this indeed answers the question.  `Ctrl + Fn + S` (not necessarily RHS) is actually the shortcut for Scroll lock toggle.