# Word 2007 won't let me mouse-wheel-scroll past cursor after editing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'm using MS Word 2007 at work (on an HP ProBook 6460b, if that makes a difference) and have come across an annoying issue for which I can't seem to find a solution. I'm pretty sure this doesn't happen in other Word versions I've used, from Word 95 to Word 2013.

When I make a change on a line, say in the middle of the document, Word prevents me from using my mouse-wheel to scroll up or down past the place where the edit cursor would move out of the viewport. In other words, I can scroll down just far enough so that the location where I'm currently typing is at the top of the document's visible area, or up just far enough so that it is at the bottom. Any further, and the visible area jerks briefly as though it's *trying* to move but can't.

As soon as I click somewhere else, or move my edit cursor with the arrow keys, it goes out of this "edit mode" and I can scroll through the document normally.

I've tried looking through the settings ("Word Options" in this version), googling (which would normally find a solution in my experience), and searching on StackExchange (not finding anything here makes me suspect my issue is a really strange combination of things, but I refuse to believe I'm the only one experiencing this issue...). The closest setting I found was the "Use smart cursoring" option, which I keep turned off (don't like it, but turning it on didn't make a difference for my issue). I thought it might be related to the ScrollLock key, which my laptop doesn't have, but toggling that via the On-screen Keyboard (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/357867/109305)) didn't have any effect either.

Does anyone know how I can scroll through the whole Word 2007 document with my mouse wheel right after I've typed something?