# How to toggle scroll lock in an HP laptop without a scroll lock key

Tags: microsoft-excel

This question is in line with another question [How to toggle Scroll Lock in Excel 2010 without a Scroll Lock key in the keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/357858/how-to-toggle-scroll-lock-in-excel-2010-without-a-scroll-lock-key-in-the-keyboar?newreg=58e62c5a5dd64c07b71769aa2d9d3b45) which has been asked on this forum. I am having issues with scroll lock getting turned on my HP laptop when I use Excel.

Comment: Use the on screen keyboard as described in the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks David! but for some the scroll lock keeps turning on. I think there is a shortcut key. I was wondering if anyone has this info. I am planning to be more attentive to see if I can understand what is triggering this when I use Excel.

Comment: I think i found the answer.!!  For HP laptops it is  fn +c . It is getting triggered when I am trying to do a ctrl + c as the fn key is just next to it.

Comment: OK. I've reopened so you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As Venkata's comment suggests there is a shortcut for scroll lock at <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on many HP laptop models.

I'm not sure exactly what range of HP laptops have this shortcut, but it is mentioned several times for different models over at the HP support forum. E.g. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Scroll-Lock-keyboard-key-location-on-ProBook-450-G3-laptops/td-p/5564167